# "When I get older" or "When I am older"

Tags: word-choice

I was discussing how to use "When I am older" with a friend who speaks English as her second language. She asked me if it would be more correct to write "When I get older".

I said that both would be correct and she asked which would be more correct...

Could anyone be able to answer this?

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on what you’re trying to say.  It’s more likely that you would want to say “am older” as in: When I am older I will be able  to cross the street by myself.  But “When I get older my hair gets whiter.” could also be okay.  Informally, they are interchangeable for the “am older” sense.

Comment: Bear in mind that one of meanings of get is become: /When I get older/ "translates" to: When I become older. Get is many things: arrive, become, receive, purchase, etc.

Comment: @Lambie - Yeah and it’s all in what follow this fragment:  When I become angry my face ***turns*** red.  vs  When I become angry my face ***is*** red.

Comment: @Jim When I get angry, my face gets red. /get/ can be/ turns/ also. Dunno why you are pissed at me. I just provided my own comment, which does not impinge on yours in any way.

Comment: @Lambie -  Ha! funny.

Comment: There's a subtle nuance.  "Get older" implies something changing relative to now.  "Am older" jumps right to being older.

Answer (score 1):

> When I am older...

When the verb is **be**, **older** is a simple comparative to describe a greater age relative to the speaker's present age. It does not necessarily have any overtones regarding the state of old age.

> When I get older...

When the verb is **get**, **older** is a description of a future state- one where the speaker is showing the signs of age. In relation to a person, that's grey hair, everything heading south, etc.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: fair comment: I have changed the wording a little.

Comment: I still think you're over-emphasising the different connotations. I think the difference is slight.